# Cannot get right value from XML

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the below xml

```
 <person>
    <age>10></age>
    <name>Jason</name>
    <bankDetails>
       <bankname>WFC</bankname>
       <accountNo>XXX</accountNo>
    </bankDetails>
  <person>
```

In my code if I try to access person.bankDetails.bankname or any other field in bankDetails structure I am getting undefined.
this is how I am calling it

```
$value.bankDetails.bankName
```

Here $value is the being passed as root and it works fine for other param just not bankname and accountNo

Comment: So let's see that code :).

Comment: just updated my question with some code

Comment: I think maybe kapa was asking to see some JavaScript code to provide context.

Comment: Yes, to know what you are doing you should show how did you get that $value. That would be the interesting part :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the bankname to bankName on your codes that is why it is giving you an undefined error
try this code

```
 <person>
<age>10></age>
<name>Jason</name>
<bankDetails>
   <bankName>WFC</bankName>
   <accountNo>XXX</accountNo>
</bankDetails>
```

Comment: If the solution is matching the right case of the letters then the next question might be: "Is it better to match the code to the data, or to change the data to work with the code?"

Comment: @JasonAller Actually both works in the same way but for me I prefer to change the codes rather than the data. But that is just my preference and you must choose the way which you are comfortable with.